# Where can I get more info about these viruses?

Tags: virus, virus-removal

I've been using Airtel 3G Dongle (Data Card) on Windows and ClamWin has detected the following viruses in the dialer software of Airtel:

```
C:\Program Files\airtel\TCPOptimizer.exe: Win.Trojan.Swrort-4757 FOUND
C:\Program Files\airtel\UpdateDog\QueryStrategy.dll: Win.Trojan.Agent-1154787 FOUND
C:\Program Files\airtel\UpdateDog\RunOuc.exe: Win.Trojan.Agent-1384356 FOUND
C:\ProgramData\Mobile Partner\OnlineUpdate\QueryStrategy.dll: Win.Trojan.Agent-1154787 FOUND
```

But I couldn't find any more information about it online. I found [this page](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/32fac832b76baa0d658c3c339c9812244c53e97881bf26bb5cb72ed0fec94915/analysis/) for `Win.Trojan.Agent-1384356` that seems to suggest that a lot of other AV like TrendMicro and MalwareBytes don't consider this as a virus. Does that means its a false positive?

I'm using ClamWin because its a light-weight and offline scanner and I don't want to use any resident "heavy" scanners as they could strain my computing resources. But is there a way to disable/quarantine these exe files or should I just delete them?

Comment: @Hollowproc I checked the SHA256 checksum of mine and the one at VirusTotal and they match, so its identical to my copy. But it doesn't seem to have any more information at the moment.

Comment: depending on when the last time VT scanned it, you may want to re-scan to see if any other AV engines now recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the files to [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com) yourself and see what other AVs think about them. (I saw your link, but you should upload your copies as well) Also check [malwr.com](http://malwr.com) to see if it has any more info. There is also [HerdProtect](http://www.herdprotect.com/index.aspx).

Side note: malwr.com allows you to search by MD5 hash (you can get this from VT when you upload your files)